# Change CSS Style use $Resources

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, tags

i have question in CSS and Resources file:

CSS code

```
   <style >
#Master_Menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;

}

#Master_Menu li {
    float: left;
}

#Master_Menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Master_Menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
```

Div

```
<div id="Master_Menu" >
    <ul>

      <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LB_HeadOfState"  runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resources, MMenu_Des %>"/></li>
      <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LB_Designer"  runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resources, MMenu_Mat %>"/></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
```

i want to change the float in

```
#Master_Menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

and get it from resource file as the selected language : i try to use

```
<%$Resources:Resources, MFloat %>
```

but it's not working, could anyone help me please

Comment: Please give i need way to change float from left to right or from right to left as user select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for the problem.

i used javascript for set style

in **CSS** file:

```
.float_R {float:right;}
.float_L {float:left;}
```

in the **web form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.onload = function () {
           var lang = '<%= Session["language"]%>'
           var lan = lang.substring(0, 2);

           //alert(lan);
           if (lan == "ar")
           {
               document.getElementById("Master_Menu").className = "float_R";
               document.getElementById("Master_content").className = "float_L";
           }
           else if (lan == "en")
           {
               document.getElementById("Master_Menu").className = "float_L";
               document.getElementById("Master_content").className = "float_R";
           }
           else
           {
               document.getElementById("Master_Menu").className = "float_L";
               document.getElementById("Master_content").className = "float_R";
           }           
       }
</script>
```

**Session["language"]** is take from master page as user select

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I think I misread your need.  You want to change the float based on the language.  Don't do that in the CSS file (not run by the server), just do it inline (pseudo/example code):

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="LB_Designer"  runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resources, MMenu_Mat %>" style="float:<%$Resources:Resources, MFloat%>;"/></li>
```

**ORIGINAL:**
Resources file won't help you change class on a select like that.  Use a jquery click event and change the CSS

```
<script>
  $("#Master_Menu li").click(function() {
    $(this).css("float", "right");
  });
</script>
```

You could do more (i.e. check float and change it instead of just moving to the right), here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Answer (score 0):

```
 ضع الستايل كامل في الريسورس 
Put the full style in the resource file
Example
```

FloatOp     float:left

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" Height="100" Style="<%$ Resources:EvlResource, FloatOp %>" Width="100" runat="server" />
```